# Running Mesos via Monit

Tags: apache-spark, monit, mesos

I am trying to run Mesos (without zookeeper) using monit to keep slaves running.

I use the following scripts to start and stop mesos slaves:

*start-slave.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /home/someuser/mesos/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh 
    --master=192.168.0.241:5050 
    --strict=false 
    --log_dir=/home/someuser/mesos/logs < /dev/null &
sleep 1 
pidof lt-mesos-slave > /home/someuser/run/mesos-slave.pid
```

*stop-slave.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/someuser/run/mesos-slave.pid | xargs kill -9
```

When I start the scripts via ssh they work great. However when I use them via monit as follows the slaves register (I can see them on the online interface) but when I try to run a computation using spark, it fails in the sense that most of the tasks are lost.

*Monit setup*:

```
check process mesos-slave with pidfile /home/someuser/run/mesos-slave.pid
    start program = "/home/someuser/run/start-mesos.sh"
        as uid someuser
    stop program = "/home/someuser/run/stop-mesos.sh"
        as uid someuser
    if failed port 5051 then restart
```

*Log exerp*:

```
I0925 14:06:21.461169 10633 slave.cpp:2413] Executor '20140924-160043-4043352256-5050-7966-0' of framework 20140925-140255-4043352256-5050-11608-0000 has terminated with signal Killed
E0925 14:06:21.461323 10639 slave.cpp:2686] Failed to unmonitor container for executor 20140924-160043-4043352256-5050-7966-0 of framework 20140925-140255-4043352256-5050-11608-0000: Not monitored
I0925 14:06:21.462224 10633 slave.cpp:2018] Handling status update TASK_LOST (UUID: 8258a34e-7831-4e5d-ba55-6df2b905b5ba) for task 0 of framework 20140925-140255-4043352256-5050-11608-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
```

Am I using `Monit` correctly?

Comment: This seems to be a better fit on server fault.

Comment: When you "try to run a computation using spark", how exactly does spark call those scripts ?